# NGINX: Convert URI path to query string

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My goal is to convert all non `/` requests of my Nginx server to `/?data={uri-path}`.

I was trying with the following configuration:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 80;

        location = / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

                alias /home/....;
                expires $expires;
        }

        location / {
                return 301 http://example.com/?data=$request_uri;
        }
}
```

The problem is I end with an URI like this: http://example.com/?data=?data=?data=?data=?data=?data=

and the browser complains about lots of redirections.

Based on documentation, `location =` should have the priority but seems I'm doing something wrong.

And feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `location = /` does.

If it points to a directory and that directory contains an `index.html` file, Nginx will internally rewrite the URI, then search for a `location` to process that revised request.
**This will result in a redirection loop.**

You could break the loop by adding another `location` block to handle the final URI, for example:

```
location = /index.html { root ...; }
```

---

If the `location = /` block is intended to proxy the request, then you are missing a `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: It has a `proxy_pass` because behind, there is a NodeJS backend running.